# How to access array of nested hashes using ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

```
results = [
   {"day"=>"2012-08-15", "name"=>"John", "calls"=>"5"},
   {"day"=>"2012-08-15", "name"=>"Bill", "calls"=>"8"},
   {"day"=>"2012-08-16", "name"=>"Bill", "calls"=>"11"},
]
```

I can access the hash using the following code

```
results.find {|i| i["day"] == "2012-08-15" and i["name"] == "Bill"}["calls"]
```

How can I access email in the following code

```
results = [
   {"name"=>"John", "address"=>{"email"=> "john@example.com"}},
   {"name"=>"Bill", "address"=>{"email"=> "bill@example.com"}},
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access John's email:

```
results[0]["address"]["email"]
=> "john@example.com"
```

To print all the emails:

```
results.each do |result|
  p result["address"]["email"]
end
```

Comment: Do we know if "John" will be in the first element of results? Wouldn't it be safer to find it?

Answer (score 1):

```
results.find {|i| i["name"] == "Bill"}["address"]["email"]
```

Although you should verify that the result is not null.

See this [fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c3314/2)

Comment: Thanks @mikelowe, I didn't know about rubyfiddle.com very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
results = [
   {"name"=>"Irma", "address"=>{"email"=> "irma@example.com"}},
   {"name"=>"John", "address"=>{"email"=> "john@example.com"}},
   {"name"=>"Bill", "address"=>{"email"=> "bill@example.com"}},
]
```

and you wish to get John's email address today and perhaps Irma's tomorrow, you may wish to crate a new hash:

```
addresses = results.map { |h| [h["name"], h["address"]["email"]] }.to_h
  #=> {"Irma"=>"irma@example.com", "John"=>"john@example.com", "Bill"=>"bill@example.com"}
```